# Projecting my shapefile data on leaflet map using R

Tags: r, leaflet, gis, shapefile, rgdal

I (on Win7) was trying to get my shapefile data ([Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3d46itleoozzjz/shapefiles.zip?dl=0) are the data files.) to be displayed using `leaflet` package. But without any success. I only get the background map tile but not my data. I am able to see my data in QGIS though.  I got the following code and description from [here](http://spatialrecology.org/leafletmapping/).

```
library(rgdal)
shapeData <- readOGR(".",'myGIS')
ogrInfo(".",'myGIS')
leaflet()  %>% addTiles() %>% setView(lng = -106.363590, lat=31.968483,zoom=11) %>% addPolygons(data=shapeData,weight=5,col = 'red') %>% addMarkers(lng = -106.363590,lat=31.968483,popup="Hi there")
```

This is what I see in my internet browser. I do not see the shapeData being projected on it:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer of Victorp works. However I would suggest to use:

```
shapeData <- spTransform(shapeData, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

This CRS corresponds to EPSG:4326. 
Leaflet actually takes care of transforming from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 (known as "Google Mercator").

Now, the difference (GRS80 vs WGS84) is negligible (0,1 mm on one of the axis). And it seems that leaflet considers both to be the same Ellipsoid. However for test purposes would be advisable to have EPSG:4326.

Comment: Cool i didn't know that.

Comment: This is great answer; sadly leaflet is not returning error messages when receiving a data with an alien CRS.

Comment: Heres what worked for me.  Functions from the sf package.  Read in the shape file with `x = st_read("shape file")` then `st_transform(x, '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')`

Answer (score 8):

Hi you have to change the projection :

```
library("rgdal")
shapeData <- readOGR(".",'myGIS')
shapeData <- spTransform(shapeData, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80"))
library("leaflet")
leaflet()  %>% addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng = -106.363590, lat=31.968483,zoom=11) %>% 
  addPolygons(data=shapeData,weight=5,col = 'red') %>% 
  addMarkers(lng = -106.363590,lat=31.968483,popup="Hi there")
```

But I can't tell you why this works, i only know a little about geo and proj.